# How to style bootstrap multi select active option bg color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, background-color

I would like to change the `background-color` of bootstrap multi select active option. For some reason it's now *red*.

Code:

```
<select
      className="form-select my-select"
      multiple
      aria-label="My select example"
      >
        <option selected>No selection</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

After loading page (pic 1):

[image: on load]

When options are selected and still active (pic 2):

[image: selected and active]

After selecting and moving away (pic 3):

[image: selected not active]

How can I change the selected and still **active** *background color* (pic 2)?

I've tried **active** and **focus** *CSS* styles, but they don't have any affect on *bg color*:

```
.my-select option:focus, option.focus{   background-color: green !important; }
```

```
.my-select option:active, option.active{   background-color: green !important; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pic 2 has the following selector:

:focus on the select and :checked on the option:
`select.my-select:focus option:checked`

You cannot set the background-color, but you might consider applying a box shadow like this:
`box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px green inset;`

```
select.my-select:focus option:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px green inset;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Got it working with: 
`.my-select:focus option:checked{
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px green inset;
}`

Comment: No Problem. The Blue or orange (in your case) is set by your Browser, so you can't change those. Don't forget to mark as right answer if it helped you out:) @Selina